# How to reset zoom tool in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, tools, zoom

I want to reset the zoom tool, I don't want the rectangle to show.

I press Ctrl+space bar for the shortcut but instead of just dragging, the rectangle is showing up. How to fix this?

Before the tool was working correct.

Thanks [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Preferences > Animated Zoom` -- Make certain that checkbox is ticked.